# Multiple Nodejs applications in elastic beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, devops

I have a nodejs project with multiple services, web and workers. All these services are in the same repo with only difference being the script used to invoke them.

I want different config for each service but I also want to keep them under 1 repo. I could use environments, but then It would mess my real environments like production, staging etc.
How can I use elastic beanstalk for this kind of architecture? Is compose Environments the best solution?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to handle this, each with their pros and cons.  What I did in the past was upload my configs to a particular S3 bucket that was normally unreadable by public.  I would then create a signed URL (good for the next couple years, or whatever) and set it as an environment variable in the Beanstalk config.  Then, in my `.ebextensions/01-setup.config` (or somewhere similar), I have this:

```
{
  "container_commands": {
    "copy_config": {
      "command": "curl $CONFIG_URL > conf/config.json"
    }
  }
}
```

On startup, the container would snag a copy of the config from the S3 bucket, copy it locally, and then the application would start up with this config.

Very simple to maintain.

Comment: What would the architecture be like in beanstalk? Would there be multiple environments for each service? If so how would you handle environments like staging, prod etc?

Comment: @sidoshi Yes, I'd create a separate Beanstalk application for each environment.  When you configure it in beanstalk, you specify that `CONFIG_URL` environment variable.  That URL will be a signed URL pointing to the config appropriate for that environment.  In your S3 bucket, you'll have something like `appname-config-prod.json`, `appname-config-dev.json`, etc.